# Why are these iptable rules keeping me from browsing the internet? (allowing 80,443,53)

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

This is for my home machine. Here are the rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        7   484 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
2        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
3        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
4        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
5       99  7040 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 70 packets, 5461 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Yet as soon as I add rule 5, I can't connect to any webpages until I delete it.  I also tried not having rule 5 and having a DROP default police (with -P) for the INPUT chain, which should be the same, right?  That didn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because communication is bi-drectional and your rules are stateless.

When you ask for a web page, the response needs to come back to your computer, and that is going to be via the INPUT chain.

The rules you have created, basically would permit your computer to act as a server for http/https/dns, and nothing else.

Adding these stateful rules would basically permit any outbound connection.

```
/sbin/iptables -t filter -I OUTPUT -m state --state NEW\,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
/sbin/iptables -t filter -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED\,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working properly because you're filtering DNS incorrectly.  DNS uses `udp` not `tcp` like you have configured.  When you add the `DROP` rule it triggers on your DNS packets and drops them. In rule 3 change `-p tcp` to `-p udp`